# How to export specific DBpedia (SPARQL) to JSON for openlayers map?

Tags: json, sparql, openlayers, dbpedia

I have a question about a SPARQL query that I'm trying to get specific information by Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor for openlayers to show json as layer. I want to show [DBPedia layer](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.dbpedia.html) from the [czech](https://cs.dbpedia.org/sparql) DBpedia project by JSON.

I tried to get results from Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor, but I'm doing something wrong, because I get an error. Can u help me how to show these results please (coordinates and properties subject?

Results would look like the [dbpedia.json](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/examples/data/dbpedia.json?short_path=bb2f857) by Viglino/ol-ext

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type":"name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
    }
    ,
    "features":[ {
        "type":"Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-244152.5863772552, 5991245.584652983]
        }
        ,
        "properties": {
            "subject": "http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Gare_de_La_Croix-de-Méan", "lat": "47.3004", "long": "-2.19326", "label": "Gare de La Croix-de-Méan", "thumbnail": "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/XGC_à_La_Croix_de_Méan_par_Cramos.JPG?width=300", "abstract": "La gare de La Croix-de-Méan est une gare ferroviaire française de la ligne de Tours à Saint-Nazaire, située sur le territoire de la commune de Saint-Nazaire, dans le département de la Loire-Atlantique, en région Pays de la Loire. C'est aujourd'hui une halte ferroviaire de la Société nationale des chemins de fer français (SNCF) desservie par des trains express régionaux des TER Pays de la Loire circulant entre Le Croisic ou Saint-Nazaire et  Nantes.", "type": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Infrastructure\nhttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#SpatialThing\nhttp://schema.org/Place\nhttp://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q55488\nhttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/RailwayStation\nhttp://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing\nhttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Location\nhttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place\nhttp://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q719456\nhttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/ArchitecturalStructure\nhttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/Station"
        }
    }
```

Comment: so, the missing part here is, how did you sent the request to Virtuoso and by "error" you mean what? Moreover, the JSON shown here is GeoJSON - I doubt any triple store will return this format, you have create it manually in you application.

Comment: so, I cant to get these results from Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor actually? How did the author (Viglino) do it? I want to show some fields of property ("foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf", "dbpedia-owl:thumbnail", "georss:point" and "dbpedia-owl:abstract").

Comment: you can get the geospatial data and whatever else you want for the DBpedia resource via SPARQL, but the format itself is GeoJSON which is not a standard format of the SPARQL protocol. You can create it manually of course, it's just a JSON object. An alternative might be using some tool which does it for you. I just did a quick search via Google, maybe this one: https://github.com/erfgoed-en-locatie/sparql-geojson - it's a simple Javascript file. It takes SPARQL JSON resultset which contains a WKT object and returns GeoJSON. Looks pretty simple to use.

Comment: And you should just contact the author, I can't answer for him how he did it.

Comment: I cant make it manualy, i want to show all properties with coordinates in DB.

Comment: No idea what you're asking, but in your question you asked for this specific GeoJSON format - I told you that getting this specific format from DBpedia is not possible. But getting coordinates and properties is possible via SPARQL, no problem. Just write and send the simple SPARQL query.

Comment: By the way, no idea what you mean by "in DB" ...

Comment: ok, and how i can get coordinates and properties info from SPARQL (i want to get all properties with coordinates from czech DBpedia? I dont know SQL (its not simple for me).

Comment: *"I dont know SQL"* ... not sure how it's related to SPARQL. You said in your initial question *"I tried to get results from Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor, but I'm doing something wrong, because I get an error."* - so you have already some query which you never showed here, for whatever reason. That could have made the whole discussion here obsolete.

Comment: for a single resource it should be `select * {<THE_RESOURCE_URI_HERE> ?p ?o}` - that's it. You see, it's as simple as I said, no magic or anything. Any SPARQL tutorial would have taught you this ...

Comment: i tried some examples of SPARQL, but i get "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030" or results doesnt show.

Comment: ok, but not showing the query makes it impossible to say what was wrong with your query ... anyways, I showed a query to get all data for a specific resource in my previous comment